# How can I extract the top-level domain from a URL?

Tags: javascript

I have a different domains for example like:

```
https://www.google.com
https://www.google.de
https://www.google.co.uk
https://www.google.com/randompath
https://www.google.de/randompath
https://www.google.co.uk/randompath
```

I need to extract only the Top-Level Domain for every possible link. For this example it would be .com .de .co.uk ....

The regular expression I tried:

```
/\.[^.]{2,3}(?:\.[^.]{2,3})?$/
```

Only works, when there is no more path after the top-level domain. Does someone have a solution?

Comment: use the `URL` facility.

Comment: right now thats a really hard problem since theres 1000s of new TLDs.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

This one does not get the second level domain which is [not trivial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-level_domain) to get right without a lookup table

```js
var domains =`https://www.google.com
https://www.google.de
https://www.google.co.uk
https://www.google.com/randompath
https://www.google.de/randompath
https://www.google.co.uk/randompath`
  .split(/\n/)
  .map(href => new URL(href).hostname.split(".").pop())

console.log(domains)
```

This one gets the last or last two depending on length

```js
var domains = `https://www.google.com
https://www.google.de
https://www.google.co.uk
https://foo.bar.my.subdomain.example.co.uk 
https://www.google.com/randompath
https://www.google.de/randompath
https://www.google.co.uk/randompath`
  .split(/\n/)
  .map(href => {
    let hostnameParts = new URL(href).hostname.split(".");
    let domain = hostnameParts.slice(hostnameParts.length > 3 ? -2 : -1)
    return domain.join(".");
  })

console.log(domains)
```

Comment: Thanks. But it should display with the dot at the beginning and when it is a domain like .co.uk and .com.au -> .co.uk and .com.au instead of uk and au

Comment: I know. But what you had would not give that either. My solution is a better start. You can interrogate the second level for co/or/ and others but see my link to Wikipedia why it is likely not trivial at all

Comment: And then what happens when someone has many subdomains such as http://foo.bar.my.subdomain.example.co.uk/ ? As you've said, it is non-trivial. To do this effectively, the developer needs a list of all suffixes or a dependency that abstracts this requirement.

Comment: @BEVR1337 My second code handles your foo bar